# LibGDX ad control tutorial producing null pointer

Tags: android, libgdx, admob

I have been following this tutorial: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Admob-in-libgdx
I'm sure i have implemented everything correctly and am still getting a null pointer for the handler. Is there something wrong with the code in the tutorial?

Here is my Android Launcher Code:

```
  public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements IActivityRequestHandler{
    protected AdView adView;

    private final int SHOW_ADS = 1;
    private final int HIDE_ADS = 0;

    protected Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch(msg.what) {
                case SHOW_ADS:
                {
                    adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
                }
                case HIDE_ADS:
                {
                    adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      // Create the layout
      RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

      // Do the stuff that initialize() would do for you
      requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
      getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
              WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
      getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

      // Create the libgdx View
      View gameView = initializeForView(new PBGame(this));

      // Create and setup the AdMob view
      AdView adView = new AdView(this);
      adView.setAdUnitId("Secret Key");
      adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
      adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder()
      .addTestDevice("Test Device")
      .build());

      // Add the libgdx view
      layout.addView(gameView);

      // Add the AdMob view
      RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = 
         new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
         adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
         adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

      layout.addView(adView, adParams);
      // Hook it all up
      setContentView(layout);
    }

        @Override
        public void showAds(boolean show) {
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(show ? SHOW_ADS : HIDE_ADS);
        }
    }
```

My Game Class:

```
public static final int VIRTUAL_WIDTH = 800;
public static final int VIRTUAL_HEIGHT = 480;
public static final float ASPECT_RATIO =
    (float)VIRTUAL_WIDTH/(float)VIRTUAL_HEIGHT;

public static final int zeroMakerX = 400, zeroMakerY = 240;

public static Camera camera;
public static Rectangle viewport;

private IActivityRequestHandler myRequestHandler;

public PBGame(IActivityRequestHandler handler) {
    myRequestHandler = handler;
}

@Override
public void create() {
    AssetHandler.load();
    super.setScreen(new TitleScreen(this));
    AssetHandler.music.play();
    AssetHandler.music.setLooping(true);
}

@Override 
public void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
}
}
```

Finally the ReqestHandler:

```
public interface IActivityRequestHandler {
public void showAds(boolean show);
}
```

Comment: Which line is giving you the null pointer?

Comment: Line 29 or 32 depending on if i set "showAds" true or false. @BVB

Comment: Which lines are those? Please don't ask us to count line numbers manually. Please provide as much information as possible to allow folks to quickly diagnose your problem.

Comment: OK good to know. These lines:                 "adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);" & "adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);" @BVB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is as follows:

Your `AdView` object is defined locally inside the `onCreate()` function of the `AndroidLauncher` class. You then attempt to access it outside of `onCreate()` in the `Handler` object. The `AdView` object is out of scope. You should declare the `AdView` in your `AndroidLauncher` class outside of `onCreate()`:

```
AdView adView;
```

Then in `onCreate()` you can instantiate it as you did:

```
// Create and setup the AdMob view
adView = new AdView(this);
adView.setAdUnitId("Secret Key");
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder()
  .addTestDevice("Test Device")
  .build());
```

Comment: Oh of course! Thank you! I also should mention in case another person has this problem that i had to move the handler to after the    OnCreate method because that causes a null pointer aswell.